# Iframe form should open new page

Tags: php, forms, iframe

I have a login box showed as iframe

```
 <div id="auth-container" >
   <iframe src="loginiframe.php" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0">Browser   not compatible.</iframe>
 </div>
```

Now inside the loginiframe.php there is a form submit

```
<form action="auth.php">
```

where I process my request , and I would like to redirect to another page after process but now

When submit is clicked the auth.php it process the request and redirect to next page but showed in the iframe

I would like to redirect them to account.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auth.php page could redirect to another page with the following script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.parent.location = 'home.php';
</script>
```

assuming that you're redirecting to "home.php" after authentication.

Comment: Thanks So much , it's the right answer , it works :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP too using this line:

```
header('location: account.php');
```

Comment: No , this can't work , the first answer was the right answer , cause this one   is loading inside the iframe